# Ubuntu14: TexLive2014: How to install extra packages?

Tags: xetex, texlive, ubuntu, xepersian

I'm using Ubuntu 14 LTS. I (fully) installed ***TexLive2013*** then I (fully) uninstalled it in order to install ***TexLive2014*** which I did it from an .iso file succesfully. Now I want to install an extra package: XeTex or XeLaTex & most importantly XePersian (Typesetting for Persian). I think I need `tlmgr` , but it wasn't provided within my original TexLive2014.iso. Ubuntu says I may get it by (re)installing `texlive-base` .Now the question is:

1) The `texlive-base` provided in Ubuntu's repos, is 2013 and I think I can't use it for my TexLive2014 (Am I right?), so how I may install `tlmgr`?

2) Is there any way to install this XePersian package manually. I mean copying/unzipping it somewhere? into some path? or something? Would you give me detailed command/path, please?

The XePersian package is a zip archive containing these files:

- A folder named `XePersian` inside it:

  - A folder named `img` with some JPGs inside
  - Some python files: dkun03, dkun04, ftxe012, undk02, undk06
  - Two files: `xepersian.dtx` and `xepersian.ins`
  - A ReadMe and two PDFs

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu. Also, note that TeX Live 2015 should be released in a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Update your **TexLive** (As my dear friend said in comments). Then make sure you have the following packages:

1. texlive
2. texlive-latex-recommended
3. texlive-generic-recommended
4. texlive-xetex
5. texlive-lang-arabic

Consider that you should find the packages suitable for **TexLive2015**. I think there are available in [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/?lang=en).
Also there are couple of other recommended packages:

- gummi (a very lightweight editor for latex)
- texlive-lang-english (you may need it)

If it didn't help you can find some experts [here](http://parsilatex.com/).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since TL 2015 is available for almost two months now, it's a little bit strange to refer to TL 2014, but the principle strategy should work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer He is using TexLive 2014 ... but he should be updated though.  :))

Comment: Perhaps you should recommend the update in your answer then ;-)

Comment: @Ali Torabi I'll check your solution then I'll share results.

Answer (score 2):

Texlive 2015 is now avalable.

Otherwise, run `tlmgr --gui`, in the tlmgr menu (up-left) you can change the texlive depot.

With the graphic interface you can search for the missing packages and install them :

[image]